# How do I test web pages opened in an Eclipse internal browser view.

Tags: eclipse, testing, browser

We are developing an Eclipse plugin that opens web pages in a view using the Eclipse web browser (typically IE on Windows).

Are there any testing tools that support Eclipse (to drive the parts using Eclipse/RCP) and also able to drive the web browser views.

At a minimum I'd want to be able to get elements by ID or xpath, and to send click events to elements in the browser.

We know Quick Test Pro doesnt do this, and can't see anything that explicitly supports Eclipse web browser views.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with [QFS](http://www.qfs.de/) , we used this tool for SWT/JFace UI automation and this tool also supports web. You can to check if this supports your test case.